# Setting Java Swing application name on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm writing a Java Swing application for the Mac using Java 1.6.  I've read a number of tutorials that step you through how to better integrate your Java application with OS X, but there's one thing I haven't been able to get working.  I can't get the application name (the first, bolded menu item in the Mac menu bar) to display.  By default, the fully-qualified class name of the main class is shown and I can't get it to change.

[This site](http://www.devdaily.com/apple/mac/java-mac-native-look/Putting_your_application_na.shtml) says that you have to set the following property:

```
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "AppName");
```

But that doesn't work (I'm running 10.6, so maybe the property name changed?).

When I create a new Java project in XCode (I normally use Eclipse), the name somehow magically gets set! (it starts you out with a runnable, boiler-plate application)  I've looked all around the XCode project for how this is done, but I can't figure it out!

My guess is that it only sets the application name if you wrap your Java application up in a Mac *.app package, but was wondering if anyone knew the answer.  Thanks.

**EDIT**: Interestingly, it sets the application name if I package my application in a runnable JAR file, but not if I run it from Eclipse.

Comment: that property works for me in 10.5

Comment: Are you running Java 1.5?  It appears to only work in that version..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should do the following during app initialization, before GUI is built:

```
// take the menu bar off the jframe
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");

// set the name of the application menu item
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "AppName");

// set the look and feel
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

UPDATE.
Above code works in Java 1.5, this code may not work in 1.6

For new java see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html):

1. Either use `-Xdock:name` command-line property: -`Xdock:name=YourAppName`
2. Or set `CFBundleName` in information property list file (plist)

Comment: Yes, I am setting the property before calling `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` and before I display my GUI.  I'm running Java 1.6, so I guess the property doesn't work with that version?  *Adding a `-Xdock:name=AppName` VM argument worked*, thanks.

Comment: @uthark Please improve the answer (bullet 1) with a more complete example, such as -Xdock:name="My App Name" -- it is not obvious without reading the developer.apple.com page. Thanks.

Comment: The link to documentation gives a 404. I could not find the documentation in the site.

Comment: @rockydgeekgod 7 years ago, when I answered, it was there, updated link to a new location.

Answer (score 5):

On Mac 10.7.5, programatically setting the property will work with with Java 1.6 but not with Java 1.7.

Comment: I know this is more of a comment than an answer but do not know how (or am not privileged enough) to add comments to the original question.