# Java Mac OS X Application Name Correction

Tags: java, macos, title

I have launched my application in Mac OS X. Next to the Apple icon in the top left corner of the screen appears the name of my application. This name appears as the package path of my main class (i.e. `pack.age.Uno` instead of `Uno`).

Does anyone know how to fix this annoying thing?

Comment: Maybe this Stack Overflow question will help you: ["Native Swing Menu Bar Support For MacOS X In Java."](http://stackoverflow.com/q/307024/788324)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Setting Java Swing application name on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154638/setting-java-swing-application-name-on-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been annoyed by this too. There is *no* way I know of to override in code reliably. I'll get it working with `if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")) System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name","My Java App");` but com back later and it wil be back to the "com.me.myapp". On release you can use Jar Bundler to make an app bundle and then the problem goes away.

Comment: Instead of `System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")`, you should check if it contains `"OS X"` because starting with 10.8, they dropped the "Mac" from the official name, leaving just "OS X". The only reason you would still need to check for "Mac" is if you were still working with Mac OS 9 or earlier for some reason

Answer (score 3):

Just add this parameter when launching the program:
-Xdock:name=MyApp